# How can I resolve a symbolic link in Perl?

Tags: perl, symlink

I have a symbolic name *java* or *jre* or *jre1.5* or *jre1.6* or *java1.5* or *java1.6* that will point to the respective directory. Taking into account the first instance, it will look like:

```
   java -> /usr/java/jdk1.5.x.x
```

My aim is as follows:

1. To check whether the symbolic exists or not
2. To get the value of the directory it is pointing
3. To use regular expression instead of using if-else statement in the code.

The link will be in */usr/tmp*.

I wrote some code in Perl which is as follows:

```
 $filename = "/usr/local/java";
 if (-l $filename) {
        print "File exists \n";
 } else {
        print "Not \n";
 }
```

But in case *java* is not present and instead *java1.4* or *java1.5* is present I want to search which should start with *java* and is a symbolic link.

Also I need to get the directory that it is pointing. Please advice how to  proceed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, are you sure that you don't want to use `${JAVA_HOME}` environment variable?

You can read the symlink target using builtin `readlink()` function.

To check other possibilities, you may either hardcode them all and check one by one for existence, use `opendir()` / `readdir()` builtins or objective `IO::Dir` to lookup all the symlinks in the directory and check whether they match or pattern, or even `glob()` function which may be simpler in your case.

Comment: I am sure that I am not using ${JAVA_HOME} environment variable. 

Regarding checking can't we check through req exp.

Comment: If you mean checking the name when iterating over entries in a directory, you can use regexp for that. But IMO using regexp here may be a slight overkill as you can use simpler glob patterns, like that: `<java jre?.? java?.?>`

Comment: `readlink()` does not resolve symlinks recursively. Thus, you cannot know whether whatever path it's pointing to, is yet another symlink or not.

Answer (score 13):

```
use Cwd 'abs_path';

$absFilePath = abs_path("$linkPath") ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for the linked files or soft link files. the following snippet will give the original file of the link, by resolving all links recursively

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Basename;

my $file='/dev/mapper/vg_ms1-lv_root'; #this should be your input
my $myCwd =`pwd`;
chomp($myCwd);

while ( -l $file ) {
    my $readLnk=readlink( $file );
    #print "$readLnk\n";
    my $directory = dirname( $file );
    my $fileName = basename( $file ); #not doing anything with this name
    #print "$directory\n";
    chdir($directory);
    my $linkPDir = dirname( $readLnk );
    chdir($linkPDir);
    my $next_file = basename( $readLnk );
    my $curDir=`pwd`;
    chomp($curDir);
    $file="$curDir"."/"."$next_file";
}

print "$file\n";
chdir($myCwd);
```