# resolve all symbolic links

Tags: linux, symlink

I have following structure
A -> B
B -> C
C -> D
D -> E
(A is symlink to B, B is symilnk to C and so on)

Do I any tool in linux which can resolve all the links till the actual file is found.
 eg `resolve A` should directly print E

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/20751037/1894705](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20751037/1894705) Here is the solution for the linked files or soft link files. the following snippet will give the original file of the link, by resolving all links recursively

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux, this does the trick:

```
readlink -f A
```